# onSurfaceTextureAvailable called when phone is locked

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am creating a custom video view by extending the `TextureView` and setting `SurfaceTextureListener` on it.

In some phones(Nexus 6P), when i lock the phone, both `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed` and `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` callback is given. That surface gets destroyed and immediately created. While the proper behaviour is that we should get `onSurfaceTextureAvailable`  only when we unlock  the phone.

Also, when the phone will be unlocked in these cases, we will never get `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` again because it was already given.

So any idea why this should be happening? My use-case is that i want to pause the `MediaPlayer` when the device is locked and then start it again when the device is unlocked. Due to the above buggy behaviour in Nexus 6P, the media player pauses momentarily when device is locked and then it starts again due to `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` given.

Comment: Kindly add the code